# Spring @Service that depends on Mongo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I want to auto-configure a `@Service` only if Mongo was configured.

What's the appropriate way to do it?

My thought is to use:

```
@ConditionalOnBean(MongoTemplate.class)
```

Is there a better `@Conditional` method I should use instead?

Comment: that is not a bad idea, another way to do it would be with active profiles, but your way seems simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Conditional on property having specific value.
Here is simple annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "database.type", havingValue = "MONGO", matchIfMissing = true)
```

You can use the annotation for all beans related with the specified DB for example or create config that is conditional on property